# Enable app step in SharePoint 2013 workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow2013

How can I enable app step in SharePoint 2013 workflow and use the same to set elevated permissions for my list items?

Comment: is app step is grayed ?

Comment: Yes it is grayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that

- You have saved and publish your workflow.
- You are using site owner.
- the "Workflow can use app permissions" feature is activated by going to Site Settings > Manage site features.

If the issue still so you should `Grant full control permission to a workflow` as mentioned at [The Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)